# Rails 4 Sort Users by Rating Parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the app I am building, users answer poll questions. Users have these two parametes:

```
correct_count
incorrect_count
```

When a user answers a question correctly, he/she gets +1 added to their correct_count. When a user answers incorrectly, he/she gets +1 added to their incorrect_count.

I use these two parameters to calculate the user's rating with the following equation:

```
(((user.correct_count / (user.correct_count + user.incorrect_count))**2)
  *(user.correct_count))
```

I want to sort the users from highest rating to lowest rating on a leaderboard page. I've added a column to my user called 'rating' and added it to my user_params.

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                               :password_confirmation, :correct_count,
                               :incorrect_count, :rating)
```

In my User model I've added:

```
def rating
  if user.correct_count == 0
    user.rating = 0.0
  else
    user.rating = (((user.correct_count.to_f / (user.correct_count.to_f + 
      user.incorrect_count.to_f))**2)*(user.correct_count.to_f)).round(2)
    end
end
```

and

```
scope :highest_rating, -> {order("rating DESC")}
```

In my Users Controller I have:

```
def index
  @users = User.highest_rating.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

So far, this is not working. What am I missing?

Comment: if you calculate rating inside model you don't need pass `rating` param to it

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is not working because you are not storing the rating in the User table in the database. If you store the users rating before saving it, then your defined scope will work as expected.

First, you need to generate and run the migration adding a column 'rating' in the users table.

Next, 
In `User` model:

```
before_save do
  if self.correct_count == 0
    self.rating = 0.0
  else
    self.rating = (((self.correct_count.to_f / (self.correct_count.to_f + 
      self.incorrect_count.to_f))**2)*(self.correct_count.to_f)).round(2)
   end
end
```

Now, you need to run save on all users so that you can populate their rating in the users table

```
User.all.each {|u| u.save}
```

Now, when you execute User.highest_rating, you should be getting the users sorted by their ratings.

Comment: you could remove `self`

Comment: @geeky_sh This makes sense thank you for the answer. Is there a way to have the scope use my user rating equation to put users in order of highest rating? That way I would not have to save all users every time I want to update the leaderboard.

Comment: You can do that but then you won't be able to apply pagination to the query. Pagination is applied after the users are sorted. This is why we need fields to be sorted at the db level. If you sort after you have fetched the results from the db, you will restrict sorting on only to the paginated result and not the whole